# ¿Cómo reutilizar un evento handler de jquery?

Tags: jquery, eventos

Tengo un evento `JQuery`

```
$(selector_parent).click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   if ($(selector).hasClass("active")) {
       $(selector).removeClass("active");
       if ($(".content--newRol").hasClass("active")) {
           $(".content--newRol").removeClass("active");
       }
   }
});
```

Este evento se repite muchas veces y siempre hace lo mismo, pero en diferentes elementos. Lo que hizo que me replanteara si es posible enviar el selector que ejecutará el código y reutilizarlo para optimizar mi código.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eso se puede solucionar usando callbacks, checa!

```
const clickHandler = (e, param1, param2) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   if ($(selector).hasClass("active")) {
       $(selector).removeClass("active");
       if ($(".content--newRol").hasClass("active")) {
           $(".content--newRol").removeClass("active");
       }
   }
}
$(selector_parent).click((e) => clickHandler(e, “hola”, “cómo estás”));
```

entonces podes usar este mismo callback (clickHandler) desde donde querás en tu código

Comment: Es posible enviar parámetros en el `callback`?

Comment: Claro, pero tendrías que crear una función anónima dentro del evento click y dentro de ahí invocar al callback con los parámetros que necesitas, claro, tenes que declarar los parámetros en la función clickHandler

Comment: Pudiera ejemplificar lo anterior?

Comment: De hecho modifiqué el código pero olvidé decirte. Es cómo harías lo que pedis

Answer (score 1):

Una solución que te propongo es que los elementos que van a ejecutar este evento tengan la misma clase. De esta manera, con crearlo una sola vez afectará a todos:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.test').on('click', function() {
  
    alert('El botón cambia, el evento es el mismo');
  
  });

});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  
  <body>
  
    <button class="test">Botón 1</button>
    <button class="test">Botón 2</button>
  
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```